# window.open Fullscreen not working in windows 7 IE

Tags: javascript

I have used below the Javascript to open the browser full screen(no close button)

```
popupwindow = window.open("name.aspx?Email="+Email+"&AssessmentID="+AssessmentID+"&Attempts="+Attempts+"","List","menubar=no,fullscreen=yes,directories=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,close=no,top=0,left=0,right=0,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,statusbar=no");
```

But It did perfectly work in windows xp IE's....But not work in Windows 7 default version IE browser..Please do needful for me.....

I used full screen for Online exam..I am just dont let user to switch to other window...

Thanks

Comment: It could well be that the feature has been removed as a security risk. There's lots of nasty stuff people can do with a fullscreen window.

Comment: IE 9 has the option to view in full screen by press(F11)..Could you please clarify on that

Answer (score 6):

The `fullscreen` feature which can be passed to the `window.open` function is proprietary and [IE-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#section_8). Already on older versions of windows it would behave uncontrollably and microsoft advised against the use several years ago (unofficially deprecating the feature back then and changing it to showing maximized windows<sup>1</sup>). In other words, you should **NOT** use this flag at all.

So far the bad news, the good news; the only situation where full screen functionality **makes sense** is for videos and for games. If you're working with videos then I strongly advise you to use flash to provide fullscreen support (despite all the backslash against flash currently, for the time being it's the only fullscreen option) and if you're working on a html5 game IE support is pointless and you can use the [fullscreen javascript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode#section_10) ([supported in about all browsers except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen)).

The main difference between the new fullscreen API and the old fullscreen IE flag is that the user is now shown *very* clearly how to exit fullscreen and a huge dialog/warning is shown showing the user that he has entered fullscreen to prevent abuse.

---

<sup>1 If you're interested in the details, IE6 SP2 changed the behavior of the `fullscreen=yes` flag from a kiosk mode to a maximized mode as outlined [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457150.aspx#ECAA).</sup>

Comment: HI Dave, Thanks for this...I used full screen for Online exam..I am just dont let user to switch to other window...

Comment: Ah, in that case that didn't really help, as they could leave fullscreen with F11 either way at any point in time. What I would advise you to do is create a native desktop application which forces this behavior, as that's something which should **not** be possible from the browser at any time.

Comment: Not sure whether this still works (the article is 5 years old), but something along those lines would be the way to go http://www.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/HowTo:_Create_a_boot-from-CD_browser_kiosk_with_Firefox_and_Linux (provided of course you aren't locked into IE, but if that's the case you have no serious option except fixing or throwing it away)

Answer (score 2):

Given your environment, easiest and most reliable way would be to write a simple WinForms application, which uses WebBrowser ActiveX, opens your website and goes fullscreen.

Using C# (since Windows 7 has .NET 3.5 preinstalled) this would take literally 5-10 lines of code.

In addition, from a desktop app you can [disable keys such as Windows key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which may disrupt the exam experience, blank out other monitors if the user has more than one, etc.

If you have a public website, best way would be to deploy this as a [ClickOnce app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - no manual installation or other hassle for the user, just click "Launch", and be ready to go. Works for non-administrator users too.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2005-windows7-IE 9 (Web application)